# Is there a viewer -standalone or offline -for Notation3 (n3) files?

Tags: editor, semantics, rdf

Or a way to make IE view N3 same way he successfully views RDF files?
(A way to successfully install the [N3 Editor](http://sourceforge.net/projects/n3editor/) plugin for Eclipse will be appreciated as well)

thanks ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, I can only be limited help, but here's some pointers:

The command line tool rapper (part of http://librdf.org/raptor/) can turn Turtle files into NTriples, which is sometimes easier to read, but won't help if you want a GUI tool.

Tabulator can be used offline, with file: URIs http://www.w3.org/2005/ajar/tab, it's a Firefox plugin though, so it won't help you in IE.

Comment: A Firefox plugin is totally fine, thanks -going to try it out.